# Upload progress with SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, sockets, server

How i can define the amount of data (bytes) that have been SENT using SocketAsyncEventArgs. I want to make a loading(porgress) bar. For example, the client sends a file to the server. Thanks for any help

I tried using SocketAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred it first returns 0 bytes then the full transafered file size. Which makes it impossible to track the progress of sending the data.
I would like to use SocketAsyncEventArgs because the server is already running using this method of data exchange.